# Converting PPT and XLS to TXT from Linux command line

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, command-line, microsoft-powerpoint, conversion

I want to convert PowerPoint (.ppt) and Excel (.xls) files to a plain text format (.txt) from the command line on a server running Linux. The server does not have Xorg or similar libraries installed, and installing them is not an option.

I have tried `catppt` from *catdoc*, but it did not work for me.

```
~$ catppt presentacion_16x9.ppt 
Violación de segmento
```

(The message means "Segmentation fault")

What software should I use for this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to need to use XSLT to convert the files to anything you need. See this blog: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151022182745/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx) for lots of details.

In short, you would write an XSLT that can handle the fields that you want out of the PPT/XLS files and print them in the format you want to a TXT file. It's a bit to learn, but that is the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command-line utility of LibreOffice/OpenOffice

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt presentacion_16x9.ppt
```

You may need to change `soffice` to `libreoffice`, or add the `--headless` option to before or after `--convert-to` depending on your software version

There are also out filters to modify the output options

```sh
soffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8"    presentacion_16x9.ppt
soffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8,LF" sheet.xls
```

For more information about the command and filters see

- https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ro/text/shared/guide/convertfilters.html
- https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/shared/guide/convertfilters.html
- [How to convert Calc's html document format to Excel format from command line in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/1193017/241386)
- [Convert PowerPoint 1995 files to modern PowerPoint version](https://superuser.com/q/827264/241386)