# Convert PowerPoint 1995 files to modern PowerPoint version

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am trying to open a PowerPoint 95 proprietary file, in Office 2013. It won't let me, saying to download a standalone file converter. I can't find any such converter.

Any suggestions on a product that I could use to convert these files safely to a readable format?

Comment: Did you trieg changing .ppt extension to .pps? Sometimes it does the trick...

Comment: If not, you can try this online converter: http://www.zamzar.com/

Comment: I tried changing to .pps, that didn't work. As far as an online converter, I'm dealing with proprietary documents and thus can't do that.

Comment: You need office 2003 that can resave the old format to newer format. You can also try google docs or prezi. I imagine every PowerPoint we make is proprietary. You want to keep the file private, I get it.

Comment: What about Google Docs?  It is another option that may work.

Comment: @Leptonator I tried Google Docs and it doesn't recognize ppt95 format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is there: [You receive an error message when you try to open a PowerPoint 4.0 document after you install MS09-017 on PowerPoint 2000 and PowerPoint 2002](https://web.archive.org/web/20160915082035/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970980)

For "security" reasons, the subkey `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<Office_Version>\PowerPoint\Security\FileOpenBlock` must have the DWORD `FilesBeforePowerPoint95` set to 0 or `FilesFromPowerPoint95` set to 0 to open respectively pre-95 or 95 ppt versions in PowerPoint 2000 or 2002 versions.

Comment: Does not work in Office 2007 and later. MS removed the code.

Answer (score 3):

[LibreOffice still supports PowerPoint 95 format](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/he/text/shared/guide/convertfilters.html) (I've tried it on my PC) so you can use it for this purpose

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pptx powerpoint95.ppt
```

The output format can have an optional filter when there are multiple versions. For example to convert from PPT95 to PPT97 use

```
soffice --headless --convert-to ppt:"MS PowerPoint 97" powerpoint95.ppt
```

The filter for PowerPoint 95 is "PowerPoint 3" as per the above documentation

In some versions you need to use `libreoffice` instead of `soffice`. And sometimes you need to move `--headless` to *after* `--convert-to` although in other cases you can omit it. I believe you can do the same with OpenOffice

You can also use [unoconv](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv) since it can convert *"between any document format supported by LibreOffice/OpenOffice"*

```
unoconv -f pptx powerpoint95.ppt
```

See also [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1600048/241386) or [this blog](https://outofmymind.scanlen.com/?p=2390) in case you want to do mass conversion

Answer (score 0):

Source [PowerPoint won't open my older PowerPoint presentations](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00916_PowerPoint_won-t_open_my_older_PowerPoint_presentations.htm)

> You try to open an older file and see a message like this:
>
> PowerPoint can't open the type of file represented by [your
>   presentation file's name]
>
> PowerPoint 2010, 2007, and 2003 with Service Pack 3 (SP3) or later
>   won't open files that were saved in either the PPT 95 format or the
>   PowerPoint 97-XXXX & PowerPoint 95 format (where XXXX is 2000, 2002 or
>   2003, depending on the version of PPT).
>
> See below if you're using PowerPoint 2003 with SP3. If you have 2007
>   or 2010, you can't force them to open these older files. If you really
>   need access to the files, here are a few possibilities:
>
> - Check to see if the file is "blocked". Right-click the file's icon, choose Properties. At the bottom of the General tab of the
>     Properties dialog, look for a security message and a button marked
>     Unblock. If the button appears, click it to unblock the file, close
>     the Properties dialog box, then try opening it in PowerPoint again.
> - Find a computer with PowerPoint 2003 or earlier, open the files there, then save them in normal PowerPoint format.
> - [Check with online file-conversion powerhouse, Zamzar, who has a solution for
>     you](http://blog.zamzar.com/2012/04/17/open-old-powerpoint-presentations-in-office-2007-and-office2010/)
> - [Try this clever trick from PowerPoint MVP John Wilson](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/convert_PPT_95.html).
> - If you have Open Office, you might be able to open the files in it then save to the current PowerPoint format and then open the files
>     in PowerPoint.
>
> PowerPoint 2003 with Service Pack 3 (SP3)
>
> Lately some PowerPoint 2003 users have been unable to open some older
>   file types due to changes introduced in Service Pack 3 (SP3) for
>   Office 2003.
>
> [This Microsoft Knowledgebase article describes the problem and
>   suggests some fixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938810/en-us)
>   that involve making registry changes. The article includes links to
>   REG files that solve the problems described.