# How to convert Calc's html document format to Excel format from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, bash, html, libreoffice

I have an html file like this this that can be opened with Libreoffice
and then export to Excel

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Tables</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 (Linux)">
    <meta name="created" content="20170328;3115845446710">
    <meta name="changed" content="20170328;3152295681061">

    <style type="text/css"><!-- 
        body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Liberation Sans"; font-size:x-small }
         -->
    </style>
```

But I want to know if there exists a method for doing this via command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file can be opened normally in LibreOffice then you can use this

```
libreoffice --convert-to xls myfile.html
```

or this

```
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx myfile.html
```

depending on which format you want. Change `libreoffice` to `soffice` if the former isn't available on your system

Sometimes (especially if you're using an old version of LibreOffice) you also need `--headless` option

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to xlsx myfile.html
```

You can also use [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv)

```
unoconv -f xlsx myfile.html
```